# Uploading pdf in database using spring/hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, pdf, upload

How to upload pdf in database using spring/hibernate annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good tutorial is here.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/